# Match single backslash in regular expression

Tags: regex, string, r

I'm trying to match a string containing a single backslash using a regular expression. For example,

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("http://www.nytimes.com")
```

`x` now contains the contents of a webpage, which include many single backslashes. For example, right near the start of this string we have `lang=\"en\"`. Now suppose I want to match this with a regular expression function, such as `grep`. However,

```
> grep("lang=\\", x)
Error in grep("lang=\\", x) : 
  invalid regular expression, reason 'Trailing backslash'
```

and,

```
> grep("lang=\\\\", x)
integer(0)
```

And using three backslashes doesn't work either, as R will see `grep("lang=\\\", x)` as an incomplete clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use `fixed = TRUE` so that the backslash is interpreted literally:

```
grep("lang=\\", x, fixed = TRUE)
```

However in the example you provide this still returns integer(0). The reason is that the \ you see in the printed x value are escape characters themselves. Try searching for 'lang="' instead note the escaped quotation:

```
grep("lang=\"", x, fixed = TRUE)
```