# using grep to find strings with backslashes - Character Escaping

Tags: r, regex, escaping

I am having difficulties to use `\` as a chatterer within a regular expression. Any ideas how to make that work?

```
grep(pattern = '\', "text with \ backslash", value = T )
# Expected output: [1] "text with  backslash"
```

Comment: I found another answer by @tmpname12345 using `fixed=TRUE` with `grep`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766647/match-single-backslash-in-regular-expression

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A single `\` in an R string is invalid because `\` is an escape character. A single backslash is actually represented by two backslashes `\\`. The first one serves as an escape character, the second one is the actual backslash. The function `cat` can be used to print the final string (in contrast to the internal R representation).

```
text <- "text with \\ backslash"
text
# [1] "text with \\ backslash"
cat(text)
# text with \ backslash
```

Because a single backslash in an R string is represented by two backslashes `\\`, you need *four* backslashes `\\\\` in your regular expression. This is due to `\` being an escape character in regular expressions as well. Hence, `\\\\` can be interpreted as two times `\\`.

```
grep(pattern = '\\\\', text, value = TRUE)
# [1] "text with \\ backslash"
```

Comment: Thank you Sven. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace `\` symbol with  to get `"text with  backslash"`, you can try to use `gsub`

```
gsub(x ="text with \ backslash",pattern = "\\\\", replacement = "",fixed = T)
```

For more information of symbol expression, you can check this document in page 59:
http://gastonsanchez.com/Handling_and_Processing_Strings_in_R.pdf